# Java Array homework

Tags: java, arrays, int

I'm new to stack overflow and I'm trying to help a friend with their programming homework.

So far we have this

```
package range;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Range 
{
    static int[] series = new int[100];
    static int seriesLength = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner t  = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean run = true;

        while(run)
        {
            int option;
            System.out.println("1. Loading a range of up to 100 numbers");
            System.out.println("2. Showing the range of given(loaded) numbers");
            System.out.println("3. Determination of the middle value of the series");
            System.out.println("4. Determination of the biggest element of the series");
            System.out.println("5. Determination of the smallest element of the series\n");
            System.out.println("Enter the number of the option you want (1-5), or 0 to end");
            option = t.nextInt();

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    System.out.println("Please input a number from 1 -100");
                    seriesLength = t.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(seriesLength);
                    if((seriesLength < 1) || (seriesLength > 100))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input, series must be between 1 and 100.\nPress any key to try again.\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < seriesLength; i++)
                    {
                        series[i] = i+1;
                    } 
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    System.out.println(seriesLength);
                    if(seriesLength == 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("You must first load a series of numbers\n");
                        break;              

                    }
                    showSeries(series, seriesLength);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    if(seriesLength == 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("You must first load a series of numbers\n"); 
                        break;      
                    }
                    middleNum(series, seriesLength);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    if(seriesLength == 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("You must first load a series of numbers\n"); 
                        break;              

                    }
                    biggestNum(series, seriesLength);
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    if(seriesLength == 0) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("You must first load a series of numbers\n"); 
                        break;              

                    }
                    smallestNum(series, seriesLength);
                    break;
                }

                case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println("BYE, DOBRO DOBRO."); 
                    run = false;
                    break;                  
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input"); 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void showSeries(int[] input, int range)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(input[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void biggestNum(int[] input, int range)
    {
        Arrays.sort(input);
        System.out.println(input[0]);
    }

    public static void middleNum(int[] input, int range)
    {
        int Middle = input.length / 2;
        if ((input.length % 2) > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(input[Middle]);
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println((input[Middle-1] + input[Middle]) / 2.0);
        }
    }

    public static void smallestNum(int[] input, int range)
    {
        Arrays.sort(input);
        for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(input[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The task was to write a program which works with an array of numbers using a menu
with few options. But also the task of each option needs to be a separate method and the main method needs to only show the menu and call for each method depending on the number(option) chosen. Also needs to check users errors, example if option 2 is chosen before option 1 or the chosen option doesn't exist and etc.

I'm confused on how to proceed as I'm no expert in java. How would this be done considering that the only things can be used are defined by the task

Comment: So are you asking how to write and use methods in Java?

Comment: What does "confused on how to proceed" mean?

Comment: Have the method return an array?

Comment: I'm confused on how to properly do the methods. The arrays aren't dynamic and must have a defined size. But I'm expected to make an array to load numbers to from another methods and then use that array in other methods. As it stands the methods that use Arrays.sort returns mostly 0's because the of all the wasted space in the 100 element array.

Comment: Has your friend's instructor only taught arrays, or can your friend also use `ArrayList`?

Comment: Have you considered using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29)

Comment: Isn't range supposed to be largest number minus smallest number?

Comment: It's translated from another language, so the word range, series, array, and list are all from the same word. My friend is unsure of the context too. But yes I considered array list, but it has not been taught yet.

Comment: SO when you ask show range of numbers, does that mean for the user to select the size of the the array?

Comment: No, for now we assume that means to print out the array, there needs to be another method like loadSeries which creates the array at a specific size and have that array be useable outside the method. I'm confused on this. Sorry for how unclear this is. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I hate these "helping a friend with homework type questions". They are half the time BS (there really is no "friend"), and the other half, when real, you want to shake the friend and say, "ask someone who knows Java for God's sake!".

Comment: I'm not ashamed to admit I'm not java expert. This is for a friend. Thanks for your input though

Comment: If you're not BS'ing us, then do yourself and your friend a favor -- have *him* ask his own questions. There's no need for a middle man especially one who doesn't know Java well. If you are BS'ing us, then stop.

Comment: A helpful user has already provided their much appreciated assistance that works wonderfully. I asked it because I am also interested in this. I have not programmed in a while and I'm getting back into it this way. Thanks for taking the time to reply though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something more like this, Where the show series method actually sets the array, so the other methods can use the array

```
static int[] series = new int[100];
static int seriesLength = 0;
...
// Get the input for range

public static void showSeries(int range)
{
    seriesLength = range;
    series = new int[seriesLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < series.legnth; i++) {
        series[i] = i;
        System.out.print(series[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Because this first method needs to be the first one called before anything, the array will be set. Then the other methods shouldn't have to take any arguments, as the array is already set, and they can just use the static array.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. I wasn't sure of setting the array size after declaration. This may seem silly but yeah.. Happens when you don't keep up with it for a while. Thank you so much, we're both very grateful to you!